# I am trying to display bar chart in Listview but I can't

Tags: android

In my task i need a display bar chart when click on button which is indicate into listView. I code for button click but when click on button application error fetch (Unfortunately closed) in adapter class of listview.

```
            holder.btnGraph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    // v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), BarGraph.class));
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can pass context instead of `this`

Comment: post your logcat please